# a javascript function called by javascript echoed by php doesn't response

Tags: javascript, php, html

I executed 2 javascript function, echoed by php code, in different ways. here is code.

```
<head>
    <script>
        aJavascriptFunction(){
            document.write( 'php echo writted javascript to call another javascript function ,outside php echo, that write this html' );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php       
            echo "<script>document.write('php echo writted javascript to write this html')</script>"; //first case
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<script>aJavascriptFunction();</script>";  //second case
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

first case, echoed javascript code that directly make function, works well. but second case that echoed javascript code that call another javascript function outside php echo doesn't work.

Could anyone explain why first case works well, but second case doesn't work?

I'm making php file that contain html, javascript and php code inside 'a' file index.php. I want to write html code basically by php echo function. What I'm trying to do is defining javascript functions, php functions separately to call from anywhere in html code(in same file) written by php echo function. I think that separating javascript and php code by separate file will be ultimate answer to my project. but for now, I'm not completely understanding how javascript and php code works in client and server. so, I need to complete my project using style above and remain understanding for latter.

Comment: You are missing a closing script tag and you have php syntax error

Comment: As Brewal said you're missing a closing script tag and also a closing ". Also, I don't know if your JS function looks that way in your code or is just for the readability of the question, but you can't just continue a quoted string on a new line like that in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is kinda messy so it is hard to work with. But I will tell you this:

```
Syntax Error on line 14, unexpected <
```

It is an issue with your quotes and semicolons.

Comment: Thank you ViruZX for commenting ! line 14 was intented new line for editing in stackoverflow editor. there is no new line character in real code... sorry i'm novice to this community so, not accustomed to rule. Thank you.

Comment: @easybb I never considered putting scripts outside of html tags "clean"

Comment: No I was saying that his code his messy -_- so literal here

Comment: @Jungyeon I salvaged through it a bit, I posted it as an answer but it violet community standards but here is the viper-7: http://viper-7.com/scshPb

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up your code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Your script has to be inside head or body -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Here is a valid javascript function
            function myTestFunction(){
                // Print inside browser console
                console.log('I was executed.');
                // Anyway if need to write
                document.write('I was executed.');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">myTestFunction();</script>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my project all javascript function is defined in <head><script> code </script> </head> sorry for making no good presentation..lol

Comment: aJavascriptFunction(){ ... } is not a valid javascript gunction.

Comment: could anyone answer this ? this is not a syntax problem please get to the point

Comment: Dude... aJavascriptFunction() <--- does not exist... run your javascript code, its not working ... your function does not exist...

Comment: Thank you very much Thanasis, you saved me from the abyss. Thank you!